# Rewrite subdirectory to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to rewrite a subdirectory from HTTP to HTTPS to no avail.  I have looked at other posts and tried to implement the solutions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} subdirectory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exmaple.com/subdirectory/$1 [R,L]
```

and also

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(subdirectory/.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and placing them either on the root directory `.htaccess` file or the Plesk's *Apache and Ngnix settings*.  But whenever I typed

```
http://www.example.com/subdirectory/some.html
```

I will always get

```
https://www.example.com/subdirectory//subdirectory/some.html
```

which is of course 404 not found.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using both at the same time? Your first rule has an issue (capture group in the regex already includes subdirectory, so no need to add it, plus the `RewriteCond` for `%{REQUEST_URI}` should check for `^/subdirectory`), however the second looks fine as long as your RewriteBase is the default (`/`)

Comment: Make sure you've cleared your browser cache. As Charles mentions, your 2nd rule block looks OK. But if you've previously experimented with erroneous 301 redirects then these will have been cached hard by the browser.

Comment: @Charles I did it only in one place. Can you put it as an answer?  I am not sure if I got you completely about the first rule.

Comment: @jack is it just that one page `subdirectory` that you want to show as HTTPs?

Answer (score 0):

To force HTTPs for just a single directory then what you can use is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(subdirectory)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(subdirectory)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What is the above doing? The first condition checks if HTTPs is **not** on, if not, then it will check for the directory `/subdirectory/` if found it will force this directory and only this directory to HTTPs.

The second set of rules is basically the opposite, forcing everything to HTTP except for the directory `/subdirectory/`.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.